# Using C structs in Python

Tags: python, c, struct, cython

I have C code that maintains some variables of type struct. I want to pass these variables on to Python code so it can be used there.

However the C variables will change over the course of some iterations. So I am looking for a way get the variables into Python without having to define a complete structure in Cython. A first example of the C structs is given below.

So how can I write simple Cython code to access the C variables in Cython without the need to change the Cython code when the C structs change?

```
typedef struct StructureA {
    int           ValueA;
    boolean       ValueB;
    char          ValueC[ 80 ];
    StructureB    *ValueD;
} StructureA;

typedef struct StructureB {
    int           Value1;
    char          Value2[ 80 ];
} StructureB;
```

Comment: For what you're trying to do, I think its better you use boost/python rather than trying to use cython which can be used to create its own .so modules.

Comment: Sounds like you should be writing a pure C binding instead of banging it in with Cython.